# Do the specials of the manga Zetsuen no Tempest continue the story after the end of the manga? Are Yoshino and Hakaze going to end up together?

Tags: zetsuen-no-tempest

Unfortunately, the English translations of the manga ends in chapter 37 and I can't read Japanese. I already know that the end of the anime differs from the storyline of the manga, since Yoshino and Hakaze end up together in the anime.

After reading some comments about the final chapter of the manga, it seems that they didn't end up together. I also heard that Yoshino rejected her in the nicest way because he thought her feelings for him would dwindle down as time goes by, and he didn't deserve her. However, Hakaze said he was the only man for her and she wouldn't give up on him.

That's why I've looked through the 6 special chapters with the hope of some hints that they do end up together in the near future, but I wasn't able to interpret something just by seeing the pictures.

Do these specials or even one of them continue the story after the end of the manga (chapter 44) and are there any hints Yoshino and Hakaze could end up together?

Comment: I have removed the links to illegal content (pointing to the end of chapter 44). I confirm with you that it's exactly what you have read about the final chapter (44) of the manga.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. I didn't know raw-Mangas are illegal, but if i think about it now, it makes sense since it's untreated i think.

Comment: Actually, except for a few legal sites (e.g. Japanese publisher website, Crunchyroll, ...), most manga reading sites violate copyright and are illegal, whether the manga are translated or not. On our site, feel free to refer to the chapter number and the page number, but not linking directly to websites which host illegal content. Sites which index manga/anime/etc. are also fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The end of chapter 6 of the extra story shows that Yoshino starts to open up to Hakaze while he was walking her home after her job (Mahiro suggested him to do so).

On their way, he says to Hakaze, if she has a boyfriend one day she should introduce him to Yoshino and he'll be happy for her from the bottom of his heart. But Hakaze replies that those things don't make her feel better at all.

Then Yoshino suggests holding hands as its dark and late and she might get lost. Hakaze refuses and says that it only applies to kids. Yoshino tells her that he can't walk as confident as Mahiro, but if there is a one in a million chance that he could get lost, he wants to hold her hand. Then both of them intertwine their fingers and walk together.

Thus, I think it's indicated that they will end up together.